# How to show specific output data using modal

Tags: python, jquery, django

I'm currently stuck with showing specific output using modal and I think it might involve jquery of some sort..but need some pointer, would appreciate it.

This picture is showing a clickable asset, that should show data relating to that asset. 
[image: modal1]

However, the template that I use right now is showing the data of all the asset as one when I click on each of them.

[image: modal2]

Template of how I make my asset become clickable modal:

```
<tbody>
   {% for item in my_stock %}  
   <tr class="d-none d-sm-table-row">     
  <td colspan="2"> <a data-toggle="modal"  href="#mydata"> {{item.symbol}}</a> 
  </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Template of my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mydata" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mydata" aria-hidden="true">
<tr class = " d-none d-sm-table-row">
   <th colspan="2">ASSET</th>
   <th class="text-right"> Quantity </th>
   <th class="text-right"> Buy Price </th>
   <th class="text-right"> Investment </th>
   <th class="text-right"> Date </th>
 </tr>  
 <tbody>
   {% for item in my_stock %}  
     <tr class="d-none d-sm-table-row">
      <td colspan="2">  {{item.symbol}} </td>
      <td class="text-right"> {{item.quantity}}</td>
       <td class="text-right"> {{item.buy_price}}</td>
       <td class="text-right"> {{item.total_value}}</td>
       <td class="text-right"> {{item.event_date}}</td>
        </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just make a modal for each of your entries and give them unique names: mydata_1, mydata_2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about making a modal for each?

```
<tbody>
  {% for item in my_stock %}  
  <tr class="d-none d-sm-table-row">     
    <td colspan="2"> <a data-toggle="modal"  href="#mydata_{{forloop.counter}}"> {{item.symbol}}</a> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

The modals:

```
{% for item in my_stock %}  
<div class="modal fade" id="mydata_{{forloop.counter}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mydata_{{forloop.counter}}" aria-hidden="true">
  <tr class = " d-none d-sm-table-row">
   <th colspan="2">ASSET</th>
   <th class="text-right"> Quantity </th>
   <th class="text-right"> Buy Price </th>
   <th class="text-right"> Investment </th>
   <th class="text-right"> Date </th>
 </tr>  
 <tbody>

     <tr class="d-none d-sm-table-row">
      <td colspan="2">  {{item.symbol}} </td>
      <td class="text-right"> {{item.quantity}}</td>
       <td class="text-right"> {{item.buy_price}}</td>
       <td class="text-right"> {{item.total_value}}</td>
       <td class="text-right"> {{item.event_date}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I used `item_{{{forloop.counter}}` and the data still show up together, just further spread out between one another.